# await Task.WhenAll seemingly completes, but it never reaches next line of code

Tags: c#, task, multitasking

I have a simple file downloader, where I get some files from a server, and then display a message informing whether it succeeded or failed. Here's the code:

```
public async Task GetFiles(IEnumerable<string> urlList)
{
    //some variable declaring, setting etc.

    await Task.WhenAll(urlList.Select(url => Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(url, dir, count++))).ToList());
    //problem lies here, the WhenAll never completes
    if (fileDownloadError)
    {
        Directory.Delete(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "downloads"));
        MessageBox.Show("Fail");
        return;
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
}

internal async Task DownloadFile(string url, string dir, int count)
{
    string filename = HelperClass.GetFilenameFromUrl(url);
    long a = 0;
    newList.Add(a);
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        TempDownload tp = new TempDownload()
        {
            id = count
        };

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, tp));
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);

        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, string.Concat(dir, "\\", filename));
    }
}
```

The `ProgressBar` I change in `DownloadProgressChanged` event goes to 100%, the files are properly downloaded, yet the code after the `WhenAll` never executes, that is it never hits the breakpoint on `if (fileDownloadError)`, no MessageBox is shown etc. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Put code in exception handler and see if you are getting an exception

Comment: Perhaps some threading exception in your code. Comment out the 'DownloadProgressChaged' and 'DownloadFileCompleted' events and see if it works. If it works the issue is with those event handlers.

Comment: @jdweng I tried it and no, it never catches anything, just happily hangs at WhenAll
-AjS commenting out event handlers did nothing, apart from stopping the associated progressbar from working

Comment: Are you debugging the code, or just waiting to see the message box? It is possible your code runs in a non-UI thread, and then `MessageBox.Show` would fail.

Comment: @Kobi I even added a MessageBox in `Main` function (it goes like `await connectionClass.GetFiles(urlList); MessageBox.Show("Test");` - this one also never fires, and it's on the main thread from what I understand.

Comment: That is console application, not something like WPF or WinForms?

Comment: I'm confused... The `Main` function shouldn't do much, and I don't think it can be `async`.

Comment: @Kobi by Main I mean the "main" function of my program (written by me), not the actual `static void Main()` - it's a form, with button/label/progressbar on it, button click calls the code I mentioned in previous comment, still nothing happens.

Comment: You do have two await which may cause the issue.  What I think is happening is the download is using a stream.  As long as the stream stays open you will never leave the await.  The server will need to close the steam for the await to unblock.  To fix the code you will need to add a method that includes continuing after the entire file is downloaded.  Usually do this by getting filesize before downloading. The stop when the entire file size is received.

Comment: Too much wrapping of `Tasks`, and the `ToList()` also not required. can you try this statement `await Task.WhenAll(urlList.Select(url => DownloadFile(url, dir, count++)));`

Comment: @YK1 tried it, your code does nothing (no files downloaded, no events firing etc.), it just hangs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breakpoint never hits if statement because of deadlock. Add ConfigureAwait(false) to all the awaits. Ex-

```
await Task.WhenAll(urlList.Select(url => Task.Run(() => DownloadFile(url, dir, count++))).ToList()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and also

```
await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, string.Concat(dir, "\\", filename)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Another optionto solve this is, to not use Wait or Result on UI thread. Use async await

ex-

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            await GetFiles();
}
```

For detail,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: This indeed unblocks the code, thanks. I will however have to do some reading on what you provided to understand why it did the lock in the first place.

Comment: Deadlock detail in nutshell: UI thread was waiting for task to finish. When task finished and was ready to return to UI thread, deadlock. UI thread waiting on task to complete and task waiting on UI thread. By using ConfigureAwait(false), task can resume using any thread in thread pool (won't wait for UI thread).

Comment: Another option to solve this don't use Wait or Result on UI thread. Use async await in UI thread

Comment: Clears it up, and the blog entry also provides good information, thanks for answer.